# Execute code before controller in Spring Boot application is called

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

I need to do some work before the controller in my Spring Boot application is called. Is it possible to only intercept the call to my controller?

I know I can achieve this with intercepting the http request or register a filter but then I would have to deal with URI pattern so that the code is only executed once.

It is enough to have my code executed just before the controller is called.

Comment: why dont you try Spring Aspect ?

Comment: I have only one case where I need this behavior. Also I'm quite sure that such a basic thing is possible with Spring Boot and I only lack the information how to do it.

Comment: You could also use BeanPostProcessor if you want to make something before or after controller bean creation, but it will be triggered only in that cases, and not in controller calls

Comment: If it is for a single controller, why not simply handle it in the controller? What is it you need/want to do that you cannot do in the controller.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to only intercept the call to my controller?

You can define an interceptor to only intercept calls on a specific uri/controller.

This is done by adding your interceptor this way:

```
registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/your/uri");
```

The complete code:

```
@Configuration
public class AnnotationSecurityConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/your/uri");
    }
}

public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterCompletion");
    }
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("postHandle");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("preHandle");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to intercept every call to every controller. But I don't want to intercept requests to e.g. static resources (js, css, images).

Comment: @T3rm1 , you can always specify paths your controller methods link to here.

Answer (score 1):

I have used for such problem the Spring Aspect concept here is some short example:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {


    private final static String pointcutExpr = "execution(* com.example.myApp.myMethod(..)) || execution(* com.example.myApp.mySecondMethod(..))";

    @Before(pointcutExpr)
    public void doSomethingBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {

        //here your code
    }
}
```

Here myMethod and mySecondMethod represents the methods that you want to execute code before them, I hope that helps